# Ocaml reverse and map

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, map-function

I have an assignment to create map_reverse function.

```
let rec map_rev func = function
        [] -> [] 
    |   h::t -> map_rev func t @ func h;;

let f x = x * 7;;

open Printf
let a = map_rev f [1;2;10;20;400]
let () = List.iter (printf "%d ") a
```

Now, the compiler will not allow this line:

```
let a = map_rev f [1;2;10;20;400]
```

because:

```
'This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type 'c -> 'd list'.
```

Could anyone point my mistake? Why does it expect 'c -> 'd list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let rec map_rev func = function
        [] -> []
    |   h::t -> map_rev func t @ [func h ];;
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of a map reverse function should be `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`. Your `map_rev` function has type `('a -> 'b list) -> 'a list -> 'b list`. So the key is to figure out why the compiler thinks `func` returns a list.

Comment: +1 for not just giving the answer. I expect a lot of OCaml questions since that Mooc came out...people might come here and ruin the educational experience for others by getting their questions all answers.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I agree that it's not particularly helpful just to provide working code to people learning the language. Hints and followup questions are far more useful.